# Fixed orientation Activity lifecycle on a slide out keypad phone

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, onconfigurationchanged

I have an `Activity` with a fixed orientation, `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in my manifest.  I noticed that when pressing Cntl-F11 on the emulator and when a user slides out the keyboard on a device the `Activity` is destroyed and `onCreate` is called.

Yet when I use a non-slide out keyboard device the `Activity` is never destroyed, simply because it is locked to portrait.

Why is there a difference in behavior between devices?  Why is an Activity that is locked to portrait, invoking a configuration change?  This is really irritating.

**Edit:**  I also experimented with `android:configChanges="orientation` without any noticeable difference.

Comment: Does android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" help?

Comment: +1. That prevented the configuration change.  I'd still be interested in a full answer with some explanation as to `WHY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably prevent this by telling Android you want to handle the configuration changes yourself via the [configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) attribute.

However, doesn't this point out why it is a bad idea to force the app to be in portrait?  That is really annoying on phones with a keyboard.

Comment: I knew this was going to come up.  I originally had this and experimented both ways without success.  The keypad is not used in the activity that is forced to portrait.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what your app is, but keep in mind that some users navigate using only the arrow keys or trackball.  If they have a keyboard, then the keyboard will be open since that is generally where the arrow keys are.

Comment: My guess as to why would be just an implementation detail of how the portrait only is implemented.  The phone notices that a rotation has happened, they kill your activity to create the landscape one, but then realize that you want portrait only so create another portrait one.  However, thats just a guess.  If you want concrete details you probably need to check out the code.

Comment: Well, onCreate is only called once when the config changes with a keyboard even with portrait set.  I guess `screenOrientation` just isn't a concrete parameter like I expected.